# how to get magento ecommerse payment method saved cc without payment gateway?

Tags: payment-methods, pci

I have created an online store in magento online store, everything is working well but am not getting saved cc option in payment method. why am not getting this option?

Answer (score 1):

Magento should come with a payment method Saved CC ready to be used. You can activate it via `System->Configuration->Sales->Payment Methods` then there should be a method `Saved CC` which you can activate and set-up as needed.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that you'll be giving yourself lots of PCI DSS compliance issues with using that method.

Comment: Saved CC should simply be removed from CE. If you need to save CC data, you should be on EE.

Comment: It's easy to detect the ecommerce software platform. It's also easy to place a test order with stolen credit cards to see if that software platform stores credit cards. At that point you've been detected as a user of hacker bait and the bite will be painful. Just letting you know so you don't wade in blind and then suffer the consequences without warning. The Internet is really helpful at giving people a loaded gun, telling them to hold the barrel to their temple and having them pull the trigger.

Comment: @pspahn - On EE with properly set up server separation and security. There are a couple more steps that just using EE. Totally agree that CE removal is a good idea.

Comment: @FiascoLabs Yeah, I know there is more to it than that, and not that a CE site couldn't do it legitimately. I think I could rephrase it to say, "... you should *at least* be on EE."

Comment: And after the exploitation of SUPEE-5344 Shoplift, there was an outbreak of questions on "I've been hacked, how do I remove the credit cards from my Magento database". Horses gone, how can I close the barn door question, eh? They have your database, they have your encryption key, even EE won't protect you...

Comment: I can't find my article I wrote, but here are examples about fines. Hopefully none of your employees alerts your bank (some banks do give a whistleblower bonus) http://www.focusonpci.com/site/index.php/PCI-101/pci-noncompliant-consequences.html